# Difficulties with CSS grid-area and grid-template-area not displaying correctly

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to generate a layout with CSS grid that will create a top div for a header and then a side div for navigation and a central div for content.  My code is as follows:

```css
.container{
display: grid;
gap: 20px;
grid-template-areas:
  "hd hd"
  "nav des"
  "nav des";
}

.hd{
  grid-area: "hd";
}

.nav{
  grid-area: "nav";
}

.des{
  grid-area: "des";
}
```

But all this does is put hd in the top left, nav in the bottom left, and des in the top right.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

u need to update `grid-area: "hd";` to `grid-area: hd;`
and `gap: 20px;` to `grid-gap: 20px;`

```css
.container{
display: grid;
grid-gap: 20px;
background-color: #2196F3;
padding: 10px;
grid-template-areas:
  "hd hd hd hd hd hd"
  "nav des des des des des";
}

.container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.hd{
  grid-area: hd;
}

.nav{
  grid-area: nav;
  height: 100px;
}

.des{
  grid-area: des;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="hd">1</div>
<div class="nav">2</div>
<div class="des">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: gap is a valid property

Comment: After adding quotation marks to the classes' grid-areas, nothing changes.